# Random variables

Tags: self-study

I've just come across a few questions on the net which I have no idea how to answer, can anyone point me towards the right direction?

1. Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are such that $X$ has mean 1 and variance 4, $Y$ has mean 2
   and variance 9, and $\text{Corr}(X, Y ) = 1/3$ What is the variance of $3X − 2Y + 1$?
2. In question 1 above, what is the covariance between $X + 2Y$ and $X − Y$ ?
3. In question 1 above, if $Z$ is another random variable satisfying $E[3X −2Y +Z] = 0$,
   what does the mean of the random variable $Z$ equal?

Comment: Regarding your question about how to format equations w/ $\LaTeX$ on CV, it may help you to read my answer [here on meta](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/reviewing-questions-and-applying-latex-format/1605#1605).

Comment: Concerning the first question, have a look at the Wikipedia page about the variance and especially about the [Sum of correlated variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables). Also, look at the definition of the [correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#For_a_population). That should get you started. For question 2, have a look at [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721/covariance-of-a-variable-and-a-linear-combination-of-other-variables).

Comment: Thanks for the post but the wiki page isn't helping at all, are there any examples I can look at instead?

Comment: You'll have to search the web for examples. Maybe you could explain where exactly you're stuck? The Wikipedia page on the variance of [Weighted sum of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables) almost provides the final solution to your first question (you have to calculate the covariance though, use the definition of the correlation for this).

Comment: Yeah, the covariance is 2 right? But I'm not sure about what a/b are. 
Edit = is it 48 for q.1?

Comment: The covariance is 2, that's exactly right! $a$ and $b$ are just numbers. In your case, you search the variance $\mathrm{Var}(3X-2Y+1)$, so $a=3$ and $b=-2$. You can drop the $+1$, because adding 1  doesn't affect the variance. **48 is the correct solution.**

Comment: thanks a lot, any extra guidance with 2 and 3? I don't understand how cov(X,X) = var(X), Is that what I should be using?

Comment: The variance is defined as $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathrm{E}[(X-\mu)^2]$. And the covariance of $X$ and $X$ is by definition $\mathrm{Cov}(X,X)=\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}(X))\cdot (X-\mathrm{E}(X))]=\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}(X))^2]=\mathrm{E}[(X-\mu)^2]$ (the same as the variance of $X$). For question 2, look at the [answer of Macro](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38722/21054) and just plug in the numbers (the result is $-12$). For question 3, look at the Wikipedia page about the linearity of [expected values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity). The answer for question 3 is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The [definition of variance and a few basic properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) should be enough to answer the questions. For the third one, you may need to remember that the expected value operator is linear.

You can work out ${\rm Cov}(X, Y)$ from ${\rm Corr(X, Y)}$ given how [the definition of ${\rm Corr}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Pearson.27s_product-moment_coefficient).

Answer (score -2):

Given

E(X) = 1,  σ2x = 4, E(Y) = 2, σ2y =  9, and Rxy = 1/3

Cov(X, Y) = Correlation (X,Y))*(SD (X)*SD(Y)

Cov(X, Y) = (1/3)*(2)(3) = 2

Random variables X and Y are such that X has mean 1 and variance 4, Y has mean 2 and variance 9, and Corr(X,Y)=1/3 What is the variance of 3X−2Y+1?

Variance of linear combination of random variable is given by

Var (aX+bY+c)=a2 Var(X) + b2 Var(Y) + 2ab Cov(X,Y)

Hence,

Var (3X−2Y+1) = 3^2 Var(X) + (-2)^2 Var(Y) + 2 (3)(-2) Cov (X, Y)
= (9*4) + (4*9) – 12* 2

= 72 – 24 = 48

```
In question 1 above, what is the covariance between X+2Y and X−Y ?
```

Cov(X+2y, X - Y) = Cov(X, X) – Cov(X, Y) + 2 Cov(Y, X)  - 2 Cov (Y, Y)

As, Cov(aX+bY,cW+dZ) = ac*Cov(X,W)+ad*Cov(X,Z)+bc*Cov(Y,W)+bd*Cov(Y,Z)

Cov(X+2y, X - Y) = 4 + 2 - 2*9 = -10

As, Cov(X,X)=Var(X) = 4, Cov(Y,Y)=Var(Y) = 9 and Cov(X, Y) = Cov(Y, X) = 2

```
In question 1 above, if Z is another random variable satisfying E[3X−2Y+Z]=0, what does the mean of the random variable Z equal?
```

Given E[3X−2Y+Z]=0

Hence,

3E(X) – 2E(Y) + E(Z) = 0

Or (3*1) – (2*2) + E(Z) = 0

Or E(Z) = 1

Mean/expectation of random variable Z is one.

Comment: Early on you seem to confuse correlation and covariance.  That creates an erroneous result that appears to be propagated into subsequent answers.