# Variance of $a^TX$ for MVN X

Tags: variance, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

How do you show that the variance of $a^TX$ for multivariate normal X is $a^T\Sigma a$?

I have $V(a'X)=E(a'X-E[a'X])^2$, but it seems like the dimensions get messed up or something after that. So I'm not sure what I ought to be doing instead.

Comment: You don't, because no matter whether you are thinking of $a$, $X$, or both as random variables, $a^\prime X a$ is not a variance: it's still a random variable.  I believe you intend $X$ to be the MVN variable, for $a$ to be a constant vector, and you probably want something other than "$X$" to appear in "$a^\prime X a$".

Comment: Following up on whuber , I believe what you want is $a^T cov(X) a$, which indeed is a scalar (variance) if $a$ is a compatibly-dimensioned deterministic column vector.

Comment: $Cov(a^T X) = E([(a^T X - E(a^T X)] [(a^T X - E(a^T X)]')$.  Hint: The order of $a^T$ and $E$ can be interchanged due to linearity. Expand and simplify.

Comment: Typo fixed, replacing x with sigma

Comment: This is really the same question as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721 but with different notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine it goes something like this (apologies for any typos or steps missed):

\begin{align}
Cov(a^TX) &= E([a^TX-E(a^TX)][a^TX-E(a^TX)]^T)\\
&=E([a^TX-a^TE(X)][a^TX-a^TE(X)]^T)\\
&=E(a^TXX^Ta-2a^TE(X) X^Ta+a^TE(X)E(X^T)a)\\
&=a^TE(XX^T)a-2a^TE(X)E(X^T)a+a^TE(X)E(X^T)a\\
&=a^TE(XX^T)a-a^TE(X)E(X^T) a\\
&=a^T[E(XX^T)a-E(X)E(X^T)a]\\
&=a^T[E(XX^T)-E(X)E(X^T)]a\\
&=a^T\Sigma a
\end{align}

where $\Sigma=E(XX^T)-E(X)E(X^T)$

which should make sense since it looks familiar to the typical variance formula we are used to, namely:

$$V(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$$
and if you multiplied that by a scalar $a$ then you would have
$$V(aX)=a^2(E(X^2)-(E(X))^2)$$