# Within- and between-group variance does not add up to the total variance

Tags: r, variance, variance-decomposition

The variance is additively decomposable (Shorrocks 1982). That is, when decomposing it into within- and between-group components, the within and between-group component should add up to the total variance.

Empirically, however, it does not always seem to be the case, especially in smaller samples. Here an example (written in R):

```
# Income data from East and West (sample size of the two groups is the same)
East <- c(60,60,90)
West <- c(30,30,130)


# Within- and between-group variance
VarW <- 1/2 * (var(East) + var(West))
VarB <- 1/2 * (((mean(East)-mean(c(East, West)))^2) + ((mean(West)-mean(c(East, West)))^2))

# Total variance
VarT <- var(c(East, West))

# The sum of within and between-group variance and the total variance are not the same
VarW+VarB # 1828
VarT # 1467
```

I wonder in which circumstances do they / don't they add up.

Comment: They have to have zero covariance.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721 for the relevant formula.