# Covariance matrix for multivariate normal random variable

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, random-variable, covariance-matrix, random-vector

Suppose we have a multivariate normal random variable X = [X1, X2, X3, X4]^⊤

And here X1 and X4 are independent (not correlated)

Also
X2 and X4 are independent

But  X1 and X2 are not independent.

Assume that Y = [Y1, Y2]^⊤ is defined by

Y1 = X1 + X4

Y2 = X2 − X4.

If I know the covariance matrix of X
What would be the covariance matrix of Y?

Comment: Simply use the properties of covariance explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $Y$ as

$$
Y = WX
$$
where

$$W = \begin{pmatrix}1 &0&0&1\\0&1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then,

$$\text{cov}(Y)=W\text{cov}(X)W'.$$

Comment: Sorry, I don’t follow. X is composed of four random variables x1 through X4. And how did we choose W to be that?

Comment: For instance, $Y_1$ is obtained by taking the dot product of the first row of $W$ and $X$. You'll get $Y_1 = 1\cdot X_1 +0 \cdot X_2 + 0\cdot X_3 + 1\cdot X_4$, as required. Similarly for $Y_2$. Look up matrix multiplication for more info. Hope this helps.