# How general is this property about correlation and the sum of two normal RVs?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, convolution

(Cross-posted from math stack exchange as I didn't get any responses there)

Given a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ that is jointly normal with means / sd's  $\mu_1,\mu_2, \sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and correlation $\rho$, the sum of $S=X_1+X_2$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_1+ \mu_2$ and variance $\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2 + 2\rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y$.

In particular, as $\rho$ increases, the CDF of the sum 'rotates' about $(\mu_1+ \mu_2,1/2).$

Now for other rvs, not normal, intuitively it seems like something like this property should generically be true: when you add two random variables and only their correlation increases (i.e. the marginal distributions remain the same) (perhaps a more formal correlation order is needed than simply the number $\rho$), the CDF of the sum should rotate about the mean $\mu_X+\mu_Y$.

My intuition is that as the rv's get more correlated the chance that their sum takes on very high or very low values should monotonically decrease. This is clear for the normal case, but can it be formalized for some larger class in general? Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: It comes down to *how* the correlation increases.  You are asking about very general bivariate families of distributions--and the answer depends on the specific family and the role correlation plays in it.  For instance, it's possible to construct families where as the correlation approaches $1,$ the sum has a *decreasing* chance of attaining values far from $\mu_X+\mu_Y$ but other families where the opposite happens.

Comment: I guess I am asking then for some families of distributions for which this is true. But could you please give an example of families for which the sum has a decreasing chance of attaining extreme values as the correlation approach 1?

Comment: Consider the subfamily of bivariate Normal distributions where $\sigma_X^2=\sigma_Y^2=1-\rho^2.$ The variance of the Normal variable $X+Y$ is (as you may easily compute) $2(1-\rho^2)(1+\rho),$ which decreases to $0$ as $\rho$ moves from $0$ to $\pm 1.$

Comment: Ahh yes I should have said I am fixing the marginal distributions, varying only the correlation.

Comment: Again: *how* are you varying the correlation?

Comment: By comparing pairs of rvs with identical marginals that are ordered according to a stochastic order such as in chapter 9 of Stochastic Orders by Shaked and Shanthukumar. For example, positive quadrant dependance, or positive regression dependance, all of which generalize the number $\rho$.

Comment: That tells us what you might mean by correlation, but it doesn't tell us how the correlation is being systematically changed within a family of distributions.

Comment: For example, suppose $X = (X_1,X_2) $ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$ have the same marginals. Define  $ X \precsim_{PQD} Y $iff $F_X(a,b) \le F_Y(a,b)$ for all $a,b$. That's one correlation order. I am not systematically changing correlation, I just want to compare the CDF $Y_1+Y_2$ with that of $X_1+X_2$ given $Y$ is "more correlated" than $X$ in the order defined above (or some other suitable stochastic order).

Comment: Because that is such a substantial change from the question you posted, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @whuber: Is the equation "variance = $σ_{21}+σ_{22}+2ρσ_{X}σ_{Y}$" true? This would mean that for increasing positive correlation the variance of the joint distribution increases, which for a bivariate normal distribution is not ok. I reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution and https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat505/lesson/4/4.2

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721.

Comment: Ok, I was doing the mistake of thinking that the distribution of the sum of variables was a joint distribution! Problem solved.