# Relationship between std dev of difference of 2 random samples of a distribution and the std dev of the distribution

Tags: standard-deviation, differences

I am studying the analytical variance of a clinical test. In published work I observed two things: 1) when looking at a particular patient, the std dev of repeated replicates was 11.5 points. 2) when looking at pairs of replicates from many patients, the std dev was 16.

I was curious about this difference, so i simulated the exact scenario (assuming each patient is from the same distribution):

1. I generated a normal distribution of 1000 points with a std dev ($\sigma$).
2. I considered 100,000 different random pairs of samples from this distribution.
3. I calculated the difference for each pair.
4. I calculated the std dev ($\sigma_d$) of these differences.

In this simulated experiment, I noticed that for different std devs, that $\sigma_d / \sigma$ ~= 1.4. This is the same ratio as the above paper (16/11.5 ~= 1.4).

Is this a known relationship? Is there a symbolic proof of this relationship?

Comment: $16/11.5$ approximates $\sqrt 2,$ which arises because the variance of a difference of independent random variables is the sum of their variances.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721.  Thus, in a nutshell, your simulation has helped establish that $1+1=2$ ;-).

Comment: ah of course. Thank you whuber.
I was tricking myself thinking there is something special about sampling twice from same distribution. Its the same as samples from two different, but identical distributions.
Here is just one resource being more explicit about the relationship: http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/rvmnvar.htm#:~:text=For%20independent%20random%20variables%20X,the%20variation%20in%20each%20case.