# Deriving Variance of T-Statistic with Unequal Variances

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, t-test

I am trying to derive the variance of the t-distribution for the difference of two sample means with unequal variance. We are given that

$$ T\sim\frac{\bar{Y_1}-\bar{Y_2}-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{S(n_1^{-1}+n_2^{-1})^{1/2}}$$

where

$$ S^2 \approx \frac{1}{n}(n_1\sigma_1^2+n_2\sigma_2^2)$$

for large $n$ where $n=n_1+n_2$.

So far, I have tried to use the bottom part of the fraction for $T$ with the relation:

$$SE(T)=\sqrt{\frac{V(T)}{n}}$$

to solve for $V(T)$, but I cannot get to the right variance, which is supposed to be:

$$ V(T)\approx\frac{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{n_1}{n_2}}{\frac{n_1\sigma_1^2}{n_2\sigma_2^2}+1}
$$

Comment: Hi. Please state why you think that would be the expression of the variance; cite the source(s) you are using.

Comment: Apply [bilinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721) and algebra.  The former gives $$V(T) = \frac{\sigma_1^2/n_1 + \sigma_2^2/n_2}{S^2\left(n_1^{-1}+n_2^{-1}\right)}.$$ The rest is straightforward.