# How do the standard deviations of two variables transform under a rotation of the variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

If I have two variables, $Q$ and $P$ where the value of $\Delta Q\Delta P$ for a distribution $f(Q,P)$ is known. Suppose I now want to consider two new variables, which are a rotation of the original two variables if we consider them to be axes on a plot,
$$Q'=Cos(\theta)Q+Sin(\theta)P,P'=-Sin(\theta)Q+Cos(\theta)P$$
and we know that $\Delta Q'\Delta P'=\Delta Q\Delta P$. Which distributions will have $\Delta Q'\Delta P'=\Delta Q\Delta P$ after rotation?[[image]] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDbd5.png) It feels like any distribution symmetric in $Q,P$ should. I've illustrated above what I mean.  How do the individual standard deviations transform under this rotation? If I try and calculate from the sketch I've made I obtain
$$\Delta Q'=Cos(\theta)\Delta Q+Sin(\theta)\Delta P,\Delta P'=-Sin(\theta)\Delta Q+Cos(\theta)\Delta P$$
Is this correct? I am unable to derive this from the formula from the general formula for standard deviation, but can't see any flaws in my logic.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but the formula isn't right.

This question is about second moments.  All we need to do is apply appropriate formulas.  They will show what is missing from the formulas in the question: namely, consideration of the covariance. The moral is that *you should be thinking and computing in terms of variances rather than standard deviations.*

---

Suppose you have a bivariate distribution for variables $(X,Y).$  By definition, the two standard deviations are the square roots of the covariances.  When we rotate $(X,Y),$ we are applying a particular kind of linear transformation to produce a new pair of variables $(U,V)$ where

$$\pmatrix{U\\V} = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{X\\Y} = \pmatrix{aX+bY\\cX+dY}$$

for given constants $a,b,c,d.$

Because [covariance is bilinear](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721), we see

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}(U) &= \operatorname{Cov}(U,U)\\& = a^2\operatorname{Var}(X)+2ab\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) + b^2\operatorname{Var}(Y)\\
& = a^2\operatorname{SD}(X)^2+2ab\rho(X,Y)\operatorname{SD}(X)\operatorname{SD}(Y) + b^2\operatorname{SD}(Y)^2.
\end{aligned}$$

where I have written

$$\rho(X,Y) = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)}} = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\operatorname{SD}(X)\operatorname{SD}(Y)}$$

for the correlation coefficient.

Consequently, the standard deviation is the square root,

> $$\operatorname{SD}(U) = \sqrt{a^2\operatorname{SD}(X)^2+2ab\rho(X,Y)\operatorname{SD}(X)\operatorname{SD}(Y) + b^2\operatorname{SD}(Y)^2}.$$

The formula for the standard deviation of $V$ is, of course, the analogous expression in terms of $c$ and $d.$

For a rotation, you may write $a=\cos\theta=d$ and $b=\sin\theta=-c$ in terms of the rotation angle $\theta$ and plug those into the formula.

It is implicit in the vertical orientation of the ellipse in the left figure of the question that the original covariance is zero, implying $\rho(X,Y)=0.$  *In this special case* of uncorrelated variables,

$$\operatorname{SD}(U) = \sqrt{a^2\operatorname{SD}(X)^2+ b^2\operatorname{SD}(Y)^2}= \sqrt{\cos^2(\theta) \operatorname{SD}(X)^2+ \sin^2(\theta)\operatorname{SD}(Y)^2}.$$

Because taking square roots is not linear, you cannot distribute it over the sum and this does *not* simplify to the expression given in the question.

---

Finally, if by expressions like "$\Delta P$" you are referring to the standard deviations, then upon squaring both sides (which changes nothing, since standard deviations cannot be negative), your original question asks to find all circumstances where

$$\operatorname{Var}(U)\operatorname{Var}(V) = \operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y).$$

Suppose both $X$ and $Y$ have nonzero variances and they aren't both constantly zero.  Taking $X,$ then, to have a nonzero variance, we may choose units of measurement in which $\operatorname{Var}(X)=1.$  Writing $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}(Y),$ the equation becomes

$$(a^2 + 2ab\rho\sigma + b^2\sigma^2)(b^2 - 2ab\rho\sigma + a^2\sigma^2) = \sigma^2$$

where $a = \cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta.$  This has up to four solutions given by

$$\tan\theta \in\left\{ \pm \frac{1-\sigma^2}{2
\rho \sigma},\ \pm \frac{2\rho \sigma}{1-\sigma^2} \right\}.$$