# Bias and variance of estimators - Normal Sample

Tags: variance, mean, bias, estimators

If we consider the two following estimators $$\hat{\mu_1}  = \frac{\bar{X_1}+\bar{X_2}}{2}$$ $$\hat{\mu_2}  = \frac{n_1\bar{X_1}+n_2\bar{X_2}}{n_1+n_2}$$ where $X_1, X_2$ are samples from a normal distribution $N \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with size $n_1$ and $n_2$. I need to compare the estimators, in order to do that, i managed to find $$\mathbb{E}(\hat{\mu_1}) = \mathbb{E}(\hat{\mu_2}) = \mu$$ thus, both estimators are unbiased and I get
\begin{align}
Var(\hat{\mu_1}) &= Var\left(\frac{\bar{X_1}+\bar{X_2}}{2}\right) \\ 
& = \frac{1}{4} Var(\bar{X_1} + \bar{X_2}) \\ 
& = \frac{1}{4} [Var(\bar{X_1}) + Var(\bar{X_2)}] \\ 
& = \frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{\sigma^2}{n_1}+ \frac{\sigma^2}{n_2}\right]\\
& = \frac{\sigma^2(n_1+n_2)}{4n_1n_2}
\end{align}
and

\begin{align}
Var(\hat{\mu_2}) &= Var \left(\frac{n_1\bar{X_1}+n_2\bar{X_2}}{n_1+n_2}\right) \\
& = Var \left(\frac{n_1X_1}{n_1+n_2}\right) + \left(\frac{n_2X_2}{n_1+n_2}\right) \\ 
& = \left(\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}\right)^2\frac{\sigma^2}{n_1}+\left(\frac{n_2}{n_1+n_2}\right)^2\frac{\sigma^2}{n_2} \\ 
& = \frac{\sigma^2}{n_1+n_2}
\end{align}

Now, I must compare them, and $$Var(\hat{\mu_1}) > Var(\hat{\mu_2})$$

This implies that $\mu_2$ is the best estimator?

Comment: Variances being zero does not look right. How did you get there?

Comment: Use https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721 to compute the variances.

Comment: Here is a start on the variances: $Var\left(\bar X_1\right)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n_1}$

Comment: Thank you for the comments, guys! I will edit my post.

Comment: Re the edit: assuming $\sigma^2 \gt 0,$ you need to compare $(n_1+n_2)/(4n_1n_2)$ to $1/(n_1+n_2).$ Notice that $(n_1+n_2)^2/(4n_1n_2) = 1 + (n_1^2 + n_2^2)/(4n_1n_2) \gt 1$ and draw your conclusions.