# Standard deviation of two assets under normal distribution and t-distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, t-distribution

I have the following two questions it might consider easy but I need to understand the intuition behind it

Assume I have two financial assets , my portfolio return model
$$
\begin{align} \label{s2}
 w^T r_{t} =  w^T \mu_{t}+ w^T \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}_{t}\varepsilon_{t} 
\end{align} 
$$
my error vector is under Gaussian distribution $$ \varepsilon_{t} |\mathcal{F}_{t-1}  \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{pmatrix}  0\\ 
0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}  1 &0\\ 
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right).$$
The standard deviation of the portfolio of two assets can be written as :
$$\sqrt{\left(w_1 \sigma_{t11 }+w_2 \sigma_{t21 }\right)^{2}+\left(w_1 \sigma_{t12 }+w_2 \sigma_{t22 }\right)^{2}}$$

My question :  Why am I not using the correlation here for my portfolio standard deviation?

Also, if I am assuming the error is under t-distribution, how can this change my portfolio standard deviation formula ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, because $\sigma_{12}$ and $\sigma_{21}$ (when suitably normalized by the $\sigma_{ii},$ as usual) *are* the correlation coefficients.

Comment: so does this mean it is correct formula to calculate the standard deviation ?  because I was reading about the topic and I found different formula used for the standard deviation $\sqrt{w_{1}^2 \sigma_{t11 }^2+w_{2}^2 \sigma_{t22 }^2+ 2 w_{1} w_{2} \rho_{t12} \sigma_{t12 } } $ are they equal ?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721.

Comment: I am sorry I must miss something in the link you provide, can you please explain how can the property be relative to my question? sorry I not expert on statistic. I appreciate your help