# White Gaussian Noise Continuous Time Random Process?

Tags: normal-distribution

How I approach the following continuous time random process question? $W$ has a constant PSD, so it is white noise. So, $X$ is a normally distributed RV, and $Y$ is a normally distributed RV with the same mean as $X$ and 2 times its variance, I believe. To answer the question fully, I would need to compute the mean and variance of $X$ and $Y$ and apply the formula for the correlation coefficient. But, how do I compute these parameters, as well as the expected value of the product of $X$ and $Y$, i.e. $E(XY)$ ?

Problem: Let $W(t)$ be white Gaussian noise with (constant) PSD $S_W(f)$ = 1. Let $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ be the rectangular pulses of height 1 with durations 1 and 2, respectively, both starting at time zero.

Define the random variables $X$ and $Y$ according to:

$$X = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} g(t)W(t) \ dt $$

$$Y = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} h(t)W(t) \ dt $$

What is the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$ ?

Comment: Can you provide the expressions of g and f?

Comment: Would be best if I uploaded an image but I can’t figure out how to do that. 

g(t) is a rectangle function that has height (amplitude) of 1 from time interval t = [0,1] and is zero everywhere else outside of the interval. 

h(t) is a rectangle function that has height (amplitude) of 1 from time interval t = [0,2] and is zero everywhere else outside of the interval.

Comment: You can find this answer without any calculation.  First demonstrate the correlation exists.  Then note that the stationarity of $W$ implies $Y=\int g(t)W(t)\,\mathrm dt + \int g(t-1)W(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is the sum of two independent variables, both of which have the same distribution as $X.$

Comment: @whuber I can see how Y is basically X + a time shifted version of X ( from t = 1 to 2  ) but I’m not sure how to demonstrate the correlation. Since W is WSS, it is invariant with time shifts. Could you clarify further or perhaps show what you are saying?

Comment: Writing $\sigma^2$ for the variance of $X,$ you immediately have that the variance of $Y$ is $\sigma^2+\sigma^2$ and the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is $\sigma^2.$

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your help. Based on your parameters, the correlation coefficient would then be 1/sqrt(2). I’m still a little confused on how the covariance is $\sigma^2$…

Comment: Use the rules at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721 to find the covariance.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! That’s help!