# Weird coefficient, can't isolate right term for Cov(X,Y) minimizing risk function; everything else works

Tags: covariance, risk

We would like to show that $\hat{\alpha}=(σ ̂_Y^2-σ ̂_{XY})/(σ ̂_X^2+σ ̂_Y^2-2σ ̂_{XY} )$ minimizes $Var(αX+(1-α)Y)$. Note that

[image]

I am confused about the terms in red, I don't know why I am not getting 1 in the result.

Comment: Because the variance is a *quadratic* form, there is no way you can obtain powers of $\alpha$ higher than $2$ in the expression for your "risk."  You go astray at the second line where your notation drops the comma for covariances, effectively equating $\operatorname{Cov}(U,V)$ with $\operatorname{Var}(UV)$ for random variables $(U,V).$

Comment: But why do I get $2a^2(1-a^2)$? Am I not supposed to have this term?

Comment: You get that term because of the mistake in the second line.  The correct equation is $\operatorname{Cov}(\alpha X, (1-\alpha)Y) = \alpha (1-\alpha)\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y).$  This is what it means for [covariance to be bilinear.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38722/919)  To get on the right track, start like this: $$V(\alpha X + (1-\alpha)Y) = V(Y+\alpha(X-Y))=V(Y) + 2 C(Y,X-Y)\alpha + V(X-Y) \alpha^2 .$$ That's a quadratic function of the number $\alpha,$ so you can write down the location of its vertex by inspection and the desired formula drops right out.

Comment: Thank you that helps so much