# Covariance Between $x_{it}$ and $\alpha_i=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T x_{it}$ in Panel Data

Tags: panel-data, covariance, estimators

I have unit $\times$ time panel data, $x_{it}$. I have taken the time average for each unit: $$\alpha_i=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T x_{it}.$$ How would you calculate $\mathbf{Cov}(x_{it}, \alpha_i)$?

Comment: What's random here? $x_{it}$ or $\varepsilon_{it}$?

Comment:  is random.

Comment: But [covariance of random variable $\alpha_i$ and a constant is zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations), no?

Comment: I took a stab at rephrasing your question. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Yes that’s what I thought at the beginning as well but it is also zero when ai is the mean of all x_t for each individual i?

Comment: The short answer, as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721 but which you might find to be unsatisfactory, shows the value is $$\operatorname{Cov}(x_{ij}, \alpha_i)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{s=1}^T\operatorname{Cov}(x_{it},x_{is}).$$ To go any further you either need to make assumptions about these individual covariances or, by adopting a suitable model and estimation procedure, to estimate them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a famous quote

> It is faster to make a four-inch mirror and then a six-inch mirror
> than to make a six-inch mirror.

This is good advice for making telescopes and doing econometrics. Let's start with the simplest non-trivial case to build intuition: $T=2$. This means $$\alpha_i=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T x_{it}=\frac{x_{i1}}{2}+\frac{x_{i2}}{2}.$$ and
$$\mathbf{Cov}(x_{it}, \alpha_i)=\mathbf{Cov}\left(x_{it}, \frac{x_{i1}}{2}+\frac{x_{i2}}{2}\right).$$
Using the penultimate rule for [covariance of linear combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations), this means that

$$\mathbf{Cov}\left(x_{it}, \frac{x_{i1}}{2}+\frac{x_{i2}}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \mathbf{Cov}(x_{it}, x_{i1})+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \mathbf{Cov}(x_{it},x_{i2}).
 $$
When $x_{it}=x_{i1}$, that's $$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \mathbf{Var}(x_{i1}) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \mathbf{Cov}(x_{i1},x_{i2}).$$
and when $x_{it}=x_{i2}$, that's
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \mathbf{Cov}(x_{i2},x_{i1}) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \mathbf{Var}(x_{i2}).$$

To make further progress, you will need to make some assumptions about variance and covariance of $x_{it}$s across $t$.

The math for $T>2$ case is very similar.