# Can the idiosyncratic error term of a variable Y increase without the covariance of Y and X increasing?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, descriptive-statistics, covariance

If an outcome, variable $Y$, consists of a noise or idiosyncratic error ($e$) that is orthogonal to an independent variable, $X$, is it possible to increase $e$ without changing the $Cov(Y,X)$?

Comment: What operations would you consider for increasing $e$?  After all, the addition to $Y$ of any variable orthogonal to $X$  will leave the covariance unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I guess that is related to my question, are there any operations that can cause this? Will not a higher overall $Var(Y)$ caused by an increase in $e$ naturally change how the covariance is calculated because the $E(Y)$ and each individual $Y$ observation relation to that mean changes?

Comment: I suspect that after reading https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721 this will be obvious to you.