# cov(dy)=J*cov(dx)*J' where dy, dx are Gaussian and J is a Jacobian

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, covariance-matrix

I was looking at the following website:
https://sourceforge.isae.fr/svn/dcas-soft-espace/support/softs/CelestLab/trunk/help/en_US/scilab_en_US_help/jacobian%20matrices.html

Here, we have the following statements.

> Quick recap:
>
> 1. The Jacobian J of the transformation x -> y=f(x) is such that:
>
> dy = J * dx
>
> (x and y: column vectors, J: matrix)
>
> 2. If dx and dy are zero-mean, Gaussian random variables, then:
>
> cov(dy) = J * cov(dx) * J'

Two questions:

1. What do dx and dy mean here?
2. How is the second statement true when $y=f(x)$ is nonlinear? Jacobian is, in general, not constant, right? But the result of J * cov(dx) * J' is cov(dy), which is a constant? Can somebody provide proof of it?

Comment: Here $dx$ and $dy$ do not mean anything other than indicate which variable you are integrating to. The notation says that if you are integrating $y$ and you replace $y = f(x)$, and convert the problem into integrating $x$, then you need to include the Jacobian.

Comment: (2) is a statement of the [bilinearity of covariance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721) in matrix form.  It does *not* makes sense when $dx$ and $dy$ are understood as differentials.  It's really a *non-sequitur* and it needs to be read literally: they are random variables (necessarily with finite variances).  BTW, they do not need to have zero means, nor do they need to be Gaussian.