# Unbiasedness of OLS when using averages instead of full data?

Tags: regression, least-squares

So my professor used the following so show that using averages instead of the full data set in OLS Regression will not cause any bias in our estimator. I understand everything up to the penultimate equality, as that would imply that Cov(X_id, X_d_bar) = Var(X_bar), which is either wrong or I'm really missing something. I tried for more than an hour to understand this and I'm sure that there must be some obvious thing that im just no seeing.

[image]

Comment: Does "$\bar X_d$" mean $(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^nX_{id}$? If so plug this in to evaluate both the numerator and denominator in question.  It helps to exploit the [bilinearity of covariance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38722/919).

Comment: Yes, I tried this many times to just substitute and rewrite it, but i always end up with Cov(X_id, X_bar_d) = Var(X_id) =!= Var(X_bar_id)

Comment: $\text{Cov}(X_{id},\bar X_d) =\frac 1n  \text{Var}( X_{id})= \text{Var}(\bar X_d)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show $Cov(X_{id},\bar{X}_d)  = Var(\bar{X}_d)$.

Writing things out explicitly (make sure you follow each step and understand what properties of iid data, covariances, and variances we are using in each step):

$$Cov(X_{id},\bar{X}_d) = Cov\bigg(X_{id}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_{jd}\bigg).$$

We know that $Cov(X,aY) = aCov(X,Y)$ so

$$Cov\bigg(X_{id}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_{jd}\bigg) = \frac{1}{n}Cov\bigg(X_{id},\sum_{j=1}^n X_{jd}\bigg).$$

We also know that $Cov(X,Y+W) = Cov(X,Y) + Cov(X,W)$ so that

$$\frac{1}{n}Cov\bigg(X_{id},\sum_{i=1}^n X_{id}\bigg) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n Cov(X_{id},X_{jd}).$$

Finally, since data is i.i.d., $Cov(X_{id},X_{jd}) = 0$ for $i\neq j$, so that

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n Cov(X_{id},X_{jd}) = \frac{1}{n}Cov(X_{id},X_{id}).$$

By definition, $Cov(X,X) = Var(X)$, so we showed that $Cov\bigg(X_{id}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_{jd}\bigg) = \frac{1}{n}Var(X_{id})$. So it remains to show that $\frac{1}{n}Var(X_{id}) = Var(\bar{X}_d)$, which follows from

$$Var(\bar{X}_d)= Var\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{id}\bigg) = \frac{1}{n^2}Var\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n X_{id}\bigg) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_{id}) = \frac{1}{n}Var(X_{id}),$$
where the third equality follows because $X_{id}$ are independent and the last equality follows because all $X_{id}$ are identically distributed so that $\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_{id}) = n Var(X_{id})$.

Comment: Alright, so now i finally see what mistake I kept making. I somehow failed to consider that obviously $Cov(X_{jd}, X_{id}) = 0  \forall j \neq i$. Thanks for clearing that up for me.