# Showing uncorrelatedness of related random variables

Tags: correlation, conditional-probability, factor-analysis

There are two random variables defined as follows:

- $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n$-dimensional random vector) and $X \sim N(0, I)$ where $I$ is an identity matrix
- $Y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ ($m$-dimensional random vector) and $Y|x \sim N(\mu+W x, \Psi)$ where $\Psi=\sigma I$ is a diagonal matrix
- $n \ll m$

What are the ways to show that components of $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated?

Comment: What does your notation mean? If $N(x;0,I)$ means that $X$ is vector of $n$ independent identically distrtributed _normal_ random variables, then it is _not true_ that $P(X=x)$ is what you claim that it is. In fact, $P(X=x) =0$ for all choices of $n$-vector $x$.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Sam.  Ordinarily, one would just calculate the covariances: uncorrelated is equivalent to a zero covariance.  What kind of answer, then, are you hoping for?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I borrowed the notation from "An introduction to graphical models" by Murphy (https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/mypapers.html). $X$ is an $n$-dimensional random vector with $E(X)=0$ and $Cov(X)=I$

Comment: You presumably didn't borrow _enough_ of the notation, or the paper (book?) that you cite as the source is completely wrong if it actually says that $P(X=x)$, the **probability** that the random vector $X$ _equals_ the real vector $x$, is the (nonzero) value of the $n$-variate normal density at $x$. Pay particular attention to **what** is meant by $N(x;0, I)$ in your source.  It is **not** the **probability** that $X$ equals $x$; $P(X=x)=0$ for all choices of real $n$-vector $x$ as I stated previously.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I agree the notation is loose. The notation would usually be written in probability and statistics books as $X\sim N(0,I)$ where $0$ is the zero vector and $I$ is the identity matrix of corresponding sizes. Leaving aside the debatable notation for the time being, any insight into my question about the correlatedness of these random variables?

Comment: FYI here is the source of the notation: top of page 4 in https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/intro_gm.pdf

Comment: So, how about _editing_ your question to make it more readable and correct?"

Comment: @DilipSarwate here you go. How is that?

Comment: Assuming "$x$" means "$X$" (otherwise we have no information on how $X$ and $Y$ might be related), the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is identical to that of $(X,\mu+WX+\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon\sim N(0,\Psi)$ is independent of $X.$ Use the [laws of covariance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721) to compute the covariance matrix of $(X,Y).$ The only uncorrelated components will be those where the corresponding covariance is zero.