# A shifted normal random variable is not distributed according to the pushforward

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, random-variable

#### Statement of the Problem

Suppose $Z = (X, V)$ with
$$
\begin{align}
    X &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \Sigma_X) \\
    V &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_V, \Sigma_V)
\end{align}
$$
I write $p_Z, p_X, p_V$ for the distributions of these random variables. I wanted to check that if $f$ is an invertible transformation and $Z^{(i)}\sim p_Z$ then $f(Z^{(i)}) \sim p_Z\circ f$, so I set up an experiment in Python and I am not getting what I was expecting, so now I am wondering if my assumption $f(Z^{(i)}) \sim p_Z\circ f$ is wrong.

#### Minimal Working Example

I've chosen a simple transformation $f(z) = (x + v, v)$. The distribution of $Z=(X, V)$ is
$$
Z \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{pmatrix} \mu_X \\ \mu_V \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_X & 0 \\ 0 & \Sigma_V\end{pmatrix}\right)
$$
and since
$$
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{V}[X+V] &= \Sigma_X + \Sigma_V \\
    \text{Cov}[X+V, V] &= \Sigma_V.
\end{align}
$$
in theory, one should have
$$
(X+V, V) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{pmatrix} \mu_X + \mu_V \\ \mu_V \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_X + \Sigma_V & \Sigma_V \\ \Sigma_V & \Sigma_V\end{pmatrix}\right).
$$
Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as MVN

# Parameters
μx, Σx = np.array([0, 1]), np.diag([2, 3])
μv, Σv = np.array([4, 5]), np.diag([6, 7])
μz, Σz = np.concatenate((μx, μv)), block_diag(Σx, Σv)
μψz, Σψz = np.concatenate((μx + μv, μv)), np.vstack((np.hstack((Σx + Σv, Σv)), np.hstack((Σv, Σv))))


# Distributions
px, pv, pz, pψz = MVN(μx, Σx), MVN(μv, Σv), MVN(μz, Σz), MVN(μψz, Σψz)

# Transformation
ψ    = lambda z: np.concatenate((z[:2] + z[2:], z[2:]))

# Sample from distributions and compare
N = 100000
true_samples = pψz.rvs(N)
z_samples = pz.rvs(N)
transformed_samples = np.apply_along_axis(ψ, 1, z_samples)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(8, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
labels = ["x_0", "x_1", "v_0", "v_1"]
for i in range(4):
    _ = ax[i // 2, i % 2].hist(true_samples[:, i], bins=50, density=True, label='true')
    _ = ax[i // 2, i % 2].hist(transformed_samples[:, i], bins=50, density=True, label='μ(ψ)')
    ax[i // 2, i % 2].legend()
    ax[i // 2, i % 2].set_title(r"$\mathregular{" + labels[i] + "}$", fontsize=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

There is a discrepancy in the distribution of the $X$ component. In the comments it was suggested that I forgot a Jacobian term, but doesn't the Jacobian come into play in the density and not the sampling? For future reference, I think this is the Jacobian:
$$
J_f(Z) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathsf{I}_n & \mathsf{I}_n \\
0_0 & \mathsf{I}_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: The relationship you wish to check is incorrect: you appear not to account for the Jacobian of the transformation.

Comment: At this point, with three different edits that seem to modify or negate large portions of the original question, my suggestion is to take a moment and [edit] to rewrite the question from beginning to end so that it's clear what you know, what you'd like to know, and where you're stuck. It's not entirely clear if you've solved the issue or if there's still something you need clarified. The previous versions will still be visible in the post's history.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. I am aware of the change of variables formula for a diffeomorphism, and how a Jacobian shows up in the density function. However, how does it show up in sampling?

Comment: @Sycorax You're right - I have removed the edits and just left essential information!

Comment: The distribution of $Z$ is not what you say it is.  Covariance is bilinear, but your formula doesn't reflect that.

Comment: @whuber Here is how I derived it:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}[X+V, V] 
&= \mathbb{E}[(X+V-\mu_X-\mu_V)(V - \mu_V)^\top] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[XV^\top - X\mu_V^\top + VV^\top - V\mu_V^\top - \mu_XV^\top + \mu_X\mu_V^\top -\mu_VV^\top + \mu_V\mu_V^\top] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[XV^\top] - \mu_X\mu_V^\top + \mathbb{E}[VV^\top] - \mu_V\mu_V^\top \\
&= \mu_X\mu_V^\top - \mu_X\mu_V^\top + \mathbb{E}[VV^\top] - \mu_V\mu_V^\top \\
&= \mathbb{V}[V]
\end{align}
$$
I cannot find the error but would be great if you could point it out

Comment: @whuber In the final line I have used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties) property for any random vector $Y$
$$
\mathbb{V}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[YY^\top] - \mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[Y]^\top
$$
In terms of it being bilinear, I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Covariance_matrix_as_a_linear_operator) on Wikipedia. So I need to check
$$
\text{Cov}[d^\top(X+V), c^\top V] = d^\top \mathbb{V}[V]c
$$
for any two vectors $c, d\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721.  To see why your derivation must be wrong, consider the case $X=V,$ where you conclude $\operatorname{Cov}(2V,V)=\operatorname{Cov}(V,V).$