# What is the variance of convolution of two random variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, random-variable, convolution, noise

Consider two random variables $Z$ and $W$. Given the variances of $Z$ and $W$, how can we compute the variance of their convolution $Z \circledast W $?

As an example, please consider the case of noise ($Z$) in an image being modeled by a Gaussian distribution of zero mean and a given variance $\sigma_Z^2$. Suppose we perform a convolution of $Z$ with a Gaussian kernel denoted by $W$. How can we find the variance of $Z \circledast W $? I am not able to find a good reference for this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you explicitly show us the mathematical definition of $Z \circledast W $? To the best of my knowledge, in probability, the operands of a convolution operator are two distributions, i.e., the convolution of $F$ and $G$ is defined as $(F * G)(y) = \int G(y - x)dF(x)$, which corresponds to the distribution of the sum of two independent r.v.s $X$ (whose distribution is $F$) and $Y$ (whose distribution is $G$).  How do you define the convolution of two r.v.s directly at the r.v.-level?

Comment: Are you convolving the *variables* or their *densities*?  The two things are very different! The convolution of the densities is the density of the *sum* of the variables: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331973  Your example suggests the latter, in which case the variances add provided the "noise" is independent of the image.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for your comment. My apologies for the confusion. I was referring to the convolution of random variables. I think $W$ may be treated as a constant kernel without any statistics associated with it. I am wondering how the convolution of $W$ with $Z$ would affect the variance of $Z$.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the reply, and sorry for the confusion. I was referring to convolution of the variables. I think in this particular case, $W$ may be treated as a constant kernel. I am not sure how would the convolution with $W$ affect the variance of  $Z$.

Comment: @user409495 Can you define $Z \circledast W$ in mathematics symbols, as opposed to plain English? Or can you provide any reference to such definition?

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer posted, there's talk of convolution of the distributions of the 2 random variables. If these are independent, the convolution gives the distribution of the sum of 2 random variables. The characteristic function is the product of the 2 given ones.
You can get the variance from this product; it is the coefficient of lambda^2. More precisely it is the second moment of the sum Z=X+Y. Or you can compute it directly as E[(X+Y)^2].
I hope this will help.

Comment: Re "get the variance from this product:" that's unnecessarily complicated.  It is basic (and easily proven) that the variances simply add.