# Variance-Covariance Decomposition

Tags: variance, covariance

I am trying to perform a variance-covariance decomposition of a variable X. X is the sum of three variables, A, B and C. My goal is to understand what percentage of the variance in X is arising from the covariance between X and each of its components. I can use this identity:

$$
X = A + B + C \\
Var(X) \equiv Cov(X,X) \\
\implies Var(X) = Cov(X,A) + Cov(X,B) + Cov(X,C) \\
\implies \frac{Cov(X,A)}{Var(X)} + \frac{Cov(X,B)}{Var(X)} + \frac{Cov(X,C)}{Var(X)} = 1
$$

This will allow me to understand the relative influence of each variable on the variance of X. The issue is that the covariances themselves can be negative, or more than 1 (but the 3 will add up to 1). I am not sure how to interpret them in those cases.

How should I interpret each component here?

Comment: Your formula for the variance of $X$ is incorrect.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721.  The correct formula shows you cannot succeed with such a decomposition unless all three covariances among $(A,B,C)$ are zero.

Comment: @whuber His decomposition is indeed correct (note that his three components are $\operatorname{Cov}(X, A)$, etc., rather than $\operatorname{Cov}(A, A)$, etc).  But such decomposition in fact says nothing more about the linearity of the covariance operator.

Comment: @Zhanxiong What do you mean when you say "linearity of the covariance operator?" Does that mean that the decomposition does not capture the contribution of the covariance of each component (with X) to the overall variance of X?

Comment: Thanks, @Zhanxiong.  I read it too hastily!  Saunok: nevertheless, the link I provided explains how to work with covariances and tells you what *bilinearity* means.

Comment: @whuber I looked at that link, thank you. But I still don't know how to think of each component in the above expression. Is this a valid way of understanding the contribution of each covariance relationship to the overall variance of X? (Valid in terms of its interpretation.)

Comment: Mathematically, this question is asking "how much do two sides of any triangle contribute to the length of the third side"? The answer is given by the Law of Cosines, showing (a) you cannot decompose the third side into a sum of two parts separately attributable to the other sides because (b) it depends on the angle.  The angle determines and is determined by the covariance.  When the covariance is zero, you have a right triangle and the Pythagorean Theorem applies: then, and only then, does such a decomposition have any meaning.